# How to call $element in Typescript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I'm trying to call the following function in TypeScript:

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

It's used in Boostrap to start the carousel. Unfortunatly **$** is not recognized in TypeScript and throws the error

```
Cannot find name '$'
```

Any idea how to fix this so I can get the carousel to auto start?

Comment: Included jQuery library in your page? how you are using jQuery in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you dont have a definition of jquery available for typescript. you should hook the *jquery.d.ts* and your IDE should automatically pick it up and things should compile. [try to follow this setup](https://bertt.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/typescript-and-jquery-example/) and you should be ok.

Comment: Adding the jquery.d.ts fixed the issue with the '$'-sign. Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 1):

$ is a jQuery function. It's actually an alias for the jQuery object. Are you including jQuery on your project?

Comment: Joe's answer fixed it, although jquery was on my page, it doet not compile with Typescript because I didn't include it there.